# New EC2 instances launched by cluster-autoscaler are not registered to Classic loadbalancer after AWS EKS 1.24 upgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, traefik, amazon-elb

I am running an EKS cluster defined with terraform.
This cluster uses traefik loadbalancer behind a classic EC2 loadbalancer.

EC2 instances are added or removed in cluster depending on load thanks to "cluster-autoscaler" Helm chart.
Each time a new EC2 instance is launched, it is  added in VPC, in EKS cluster and usually linked to EC2 loadbalancer.

After EKS upgrade from 1.23 to 1.24, new EC2 instances are added in VPC and EKS cluster, but not added to EC2 loadbalancer (I am able to add them manually in AWS console).

I have tried to update "cluster-autoscaler" Helm chart to last version (9.21.1 as described in https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/releases) without any success and noticed it was still using 1.23 App version (=k8s.gcr.io/autoscaling/cluster-autoscaler:v1.23.0)

Setting image tag to v1.24.0 has not solved the problem.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Issue due to a bug in EKS 1.24.
Solved with EKS 1.25.